# apache httpget breaks without exception

Tags: java, apache, http, exception

I wrote a little programm, that reads an XML-File via http-get.

Loacally it's running fine.

But on the server it keeps breaking without any exception, except a nullpointer because of the empty result

I'm using the apache http lib.

Here is the class, i added the numbers, to track the exact point, where it stops working.

```
public void get(String url, String user, String pass, File outfile) throws IOException
{
    log.info("1");
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM, "basic"),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, pass));

    log.info("2");
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();

    HttpResponse response = null;
    log.info("6");
    InputStream content = null;
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try
    {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        log.info("3");
        httpGet.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        log.info("4");
        httpGet.addHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
        log.info("5");

        log.info("6");

        log.info("7");

        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
        log.info("8");
        response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        log.info("9");
        log.info("response: {}", response);
        log.info("10");
        content = response.getEntity().getContent();
        log.info("11");
        log.info("content: {}", content);
        log.info("12");
        IOUtils.copy(content, outputStream);
        log.info("13");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.error("", e);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            log.info("14");
            log.info(String.valueOf(content));
            content.close();
            outputStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            log.error("Error while closing Streams", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the log snipets; I tried to mask every sensible data and i hope i didn't miss anything

[Local log snipet](http://pastebin.com/9cteuDBq)

[Remote log snipet](http://pastebin.com/cyR0zkLP)

As you can see, the numbers stop after 8 and start in the finally block again with 14. the rest is missing and I have no idea, why.

The used URL is reachable via browser or comandline.

Comment: thank you, that did the trick. Its missing org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64. But its interesting, that this is only happening on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept. And oh nice you just reached upvote privileges. Feel free to practice doing that on my answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a bit tricky: you are running into some sort of *Error* here. Probably NoClassDefFoundError or something alike.

But as you are catching for *Exception* this piece of code simply doesn't "see" the real problem.

So to debug the problem: either check the server log files or change your code to catch Throwable instead of Exception.